# OpenCV tutorial - Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run this [OpenCV tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_epipolar_geometry/py_epipolar_geometry.html) with Python and OpenCV 2.4 but it gives me the following error :

> OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Both matrices must be floating-point (single or double precision)) in cvConvertPointsHomogeneous, file ........\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\fundam.cpp, line 901

How can I address this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using OpenCV 3.0.0 rc-1 instead of 2.4

`sift = cv2.SIFT()` has to be replaced by `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` for compatibility with this version.